# typescript import function from another ts file - file is not a module error

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I'me using typescript and cloud functions to build my backend, still very new to typescript. Trying to break down my gigantic index.ts into multiple files

background-job.ts

```
export const pickWinnerBackgroundJob = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun(async (context) => {

});
```

index.ts

```
import * as backgroundJob from './background-job';

exports.evaluateBackgroundJob = backgroundJob.pickWinnerBackgroundJob;
```

When i try to deploy this i get the following error

```
src/index.ts:8:39 - error TS2306: File '/Users/name/Desktop/Repos/App/Web/functions/src/background-job.ts' is not a module.

import * as backgroundJob from './background-job';
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any idea why it's complaining?

Comment: In my experience, the "file is not a module" error in otherwise good-looking TypeScript code is that you've got a typo in your TypeScript (or in an import) that makes it TS that can't be compiled.

Comment: `exports.evaluateBackgroundJob` looks like CommonJS, but `export const pickWinnerBackgroundJob` looks like ES6 module syntax.

Comment: the problem was I had a const named the same as the imported name, renaming the const fixed the issue

Comment: @aryaxt Could you post your fix as an answer so that other community members would benefit from it? Thanks.

Comment: I actually had a commented out identical variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was I had a const named the same as the imported name, renaming the const fixed the issue